# How can I be certain that a file was written?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have the following Ruby/Rails code:

```
file = File.new("#{folder}/conf.txt", 'a+')
file.write(content)
file.close
```

The problem is that from time to time this file is created but it's empty while I'm sure that content variable is not empty ( it's used on another part of the code too ).

How can I be sure that the file was written? As this is an important step in my application, if it couldn't be written, I would like to get an exception or some kind of error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ruby would throw some error if the data hasn't been written.

Comment: If that code executes, you will have written content to "#{folder}/conf.txt". I suspect if it occasionally doesn't get written, what's really happening is that you got an exception thrown on `File.new` or `#write` and have silently rescued it elsewhere. Could some of the folders being targeted this way have permission issues preventing your rails user from opening a file in them?

Comment: @Fernando why not seek to last line and compare it ,also file size comparison would do

Answer (score 3):

Do a round trip from the original data, writing it to a file, then read from the file. If it matches the original content, you can be sure.

Comment: While this advise is a fine way to check if the file got written, it does not address the deeper question of how the OPs code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who replied to the question and sorry for the lack of attention but 1 day after posting the question i started noticing errors like this one in Apache log ( I'm using Passenger + Apache ):

```
[ pid=21526, timestamp=1350608946 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGABRT(6), reason=SI_TKILL, signal sent by PID 21526 with UID 0, backtrace available.
--------------------------------------
[ pid=21526 ] Backtrace with 34 frames:
PassengerHelperAgent[0x525668]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf4c0)[0x7fcabb2014c0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7fcaba7059a5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7fcaba707185]
big backtrace...
```

I searched about this problem but couldn't find anyone who had a similar problem/backtrace.

Them, I decided to move to Passenger + Nginx.

After 1 week, the issue has simply gone away. What used to happen once or twice a day, did not happen a single time with Nginx. Same code ( no updates at all ) and same machine.

While i can't reproduce this issue, during the time i was investigating it, I did several tests with "File.close" method. It will throw an exception whenever it's not possible to write to the file.

Unfortunately i don't have enough experience to dig into this problem and i'm fairly happy with Nginx + Passenger.